# rerun a black list Hadoop node without stop job running

Tags: hadoop

Is there any way for unblacklisting a Hadoop node when the job is running ?
I tired restarting data node but it didn't work.

this happens after four time failure at slave1 with this error:

> Error initializing attempt_201311231755_0030_m_000000_0:
>   java.io.IOException: Expecting a line not the end of stream
>     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.DF.parseExecResult(DF.java:109)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:179)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:134)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.DF.getAvailable(DF.java:73)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator$AllocatorPerContext.getLocalPathForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:306)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator.getLocalPathForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:124)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator.getLocalPathForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:108)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.localizeJob(TaskTracker.java:776)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.startNewTask(TaskTracker.java:1664)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.access$1200(TaskTracker.java:97)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker$TaskLauncher.run(TaskTracker.java:1629)